# How can I repair a big gash in my kitchen floor?

Tags: repair, floor

How can I repair this big gash in kitchen floor (I can see wood)

[image]
[image]
[image]

I was cleaning my kitchen floor, and moved the fridge out of the way. Problem is we have our microwave on it with a short cord. Microwave fell and left a big gash in the kitchen floor of our rental apartment. I was wondering what our options would be for repair?

Comment: Is there any left over of the flooring from when it was installed?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I don't suppose there's a way to get the same type somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "fix" it without replacing the floorboard, but you can patch it to look close.

That looks like IKEA's pressboard laminate - that's not wood you're seeing, that's paper.  You can check their stock for some extra boards if there's one near by - sometimes they might have some extras in returns.

So - get yourself some dark stained wood filler and a 2" putty knife, and a small "wood stain marker" that matches the color more exactly.  You can find all of these in among the paint aisles in any big box hardware store.  You'll also want some 100 grit and 220 grit sandpaper.

Fill the hole with filler and smooth with the knife.  Let it dry and sand smooth first with the 100 grit then the 220 grit.

Finally, stain the filler to match, and let dry.

Comment: I couldn't find any equivalent on IKEA's site, but I'm not sure it's IKEA--it's an old Brooklyn apartment, the floor was probably put down before IKEA existed (though not certain).  Can you do paint matching for the stain you add to the filler?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is a manufactured floor meaning that it is not solid wood but a particle product with a laminate top. Some of these are glued together and some snap together. If the damage is close to a corner you maybe able to remove the shoe molding and unsnap the strips. You might be lucky and salvage a piece from under the fridge or move the damaged piece to a less visible spot.